# Como extrair dados em forma de índices deste array?

Tags: php, json, array, rest

Estou desenvolvendo um **[site para imobiliária](http://pier36.axitech.com.br)** e vou usar o recurso de `REST`. O código abaixo me retorna um por um os imóveis cadastrados no software do servidor conforme pode ser visto **[aqui](http://pier36.axitech.com.br/vista/stack.php)**.

```
$dados = array( 
    'fields'    => 
        array( 
            'Codigo', 'Cidade', 'Bairro', 'ValorVenda' 
    ), 
    'paginacao' =>  
        array( 
            'pagina'        => 1, 
            'quantidade'    => 10 
    ) 
); 

$key         =  'c9fdd79584fb8d369a6a579af1a8f681'; 
$postFields  =  json_encode( $dados ); 
$url         =  'http://sandbox-rest.vistahost.com.br/imoveis/listar?key=' . $key; 
$url        .=  '&showtotal=1&pesquisa=' . $postFields; 

$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , array( 'Accept: application/json' ) ); 
$result = curl_exec( $ch ); 

$result = json_decode( $result, true ); 

echo '<pre>'; 
    print_r( $result ); 
echo '<pre>';
```

A minha ***pergunta*** é: neste caso, como extrair um por um dos dados dos arrays de imóveis em forma de índices?

O que eu sei é que o **`$result`** tá guardando tudo dentro dele e ao colocar um `print_r` ele solta os imóveis. Como desmembrar estas informações em forma de índices, alguma coisa do tipo:

```
echo $result['fields']['Codigo'];
```

O `print_r($result)` imprime isto:

```
Array
(
    [62] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 62
            [Cidade] => Porto Alegre
            [Bairro] => Espirito Santo
            [ValorVenda] => 105000
        )

    [69] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 69
            [Cidade] => Porto Alegre
            [Bairro] => Central
            [ValorVenda] => 90000
        ) ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa questão é muito estranha, já que a resposta é bem óbvia.
Ora, você sempre precisará especificar um índice para um determinado registro do qual você quer obter alguma informação:

```
$registro = $results[62];
print $registro['ValorVenda'];
```

Mesmo dentro de um loop como **foreach**, o índice para cada registro é implicitamente considerado:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    print $result['Bairro'] . PHP_EOL;
    print $result['ValorVenda']. PHP_EOL; 
    print "---" . PHP_EOL;
}
```